# Exclude IE8 permutation from GWT build

Tags: gwt, configuration, internet-explorer-8, permutation, user-agent

At certain point the decision was made to no longer support IE8 browser for the application based on GWT framework. Later, during evaluation of the deployment files I noticed that they contain extra permutations signed for IE8 user agent (times number of supported locales). Removing ie8 permutations from the build would save a significant amount of time during compilation and deployment.

There is a known way how to limit the number of compiled permutations using the following directive from the *.gwt.xml file, e.g.:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie10, safari, gecko1_8"/>
```

This assumes that I don't care about other, not included to this list user agents, and helps to optimize the development process.

But now I am at the position that for production I do care about everything but ie8. Is there a better way of excluding user agents from the build other than listing "all but that one"?

If no - how to keep the list of user agents supported in production up to date? Currently we are on GWT2.7; it is likely GWT 2.8 (or newer) may support a new yet unknown user agent, that I will have not to miss and will have to add to the production build xml file. Any ideas how to smartly ban ie8 from the app?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help:
https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/ConditionalProperties

Other option is to use `<collapse-all-properties />` to generate only one permutation.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, we ended up specifying the exact set of user agents that we are going to support. That worked well in the light of the fact that the major group of the browsers use webkit or gecko engines. And then we just added the list of MS browsers that we want.

As we operate in an enterprise environment there's a certain level of connection with our customers, and we can issue the recommendation e.g., drop the IE8 (normally these are aligned with MS announced end-of-support dates), or switch to an alternative for the best experience. Customers mostly follow that, never have had big issues.